# How to read multiple lines of string from stdin in C?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

I am a novice in C programming. Suppose I want to read multiple lines of string from stdin. How can I keep reading until a line only containing EOL?

example of input

```
1+2\n
1+2+3\n
1+2+3+4\n
\n (stop at this line)
```

It seems that when I hit enter(EOL) directly, **scanf** won't execute until something other than just EOL has been entered. How can I solve that problem?

I'll be really grateful if someone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Use `fgets`. `scanf` is a bad choice in many cases.

Comment: Use fgetc.  When you see two consecutive `\n`, stop.

Comment: Personally I would use [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and stop when it returns 1.

Comment: @ShellCode `getline()` in not part of the standard C library.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and what's wrong with it not being part of the standard  C lib ? It's in the POSIX standard

Comment: @ShellCode If post was tagged posix, then `getline()` is a viable choice, else we could suggest any implementation specific solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn C, you should avoid `scanf`.  The only use cases where `scanf` actually makes sense are in problems for which C is the wrong language.  Time spent learning the foibles of scanf is not well spent, and it doesn't really teach you much about C.  For something like this, just read one character at a time and stop when you see two consecutive newlines.  Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char buf[1024];
        int c;

        char *s = buf;

        while( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && s < buf + sizeof buf - 1 ){
                if( c == '\n' && s > buf && s[-1] == '\n' ){
                        ungetc(c, stdin);
                        break;
                }
                *s++ = c;
        }
        *s = '\0';
        printf("string entered: %s", buf);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `'\n'` is the first character read, code does not stop.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the could should terminate when the first character is a newline, but that's appropriate as an exercise left for the reader. :)

Comment: Agreed - some detail left out of OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

> to read multiple lines of string from stdin. How can I keep reading until a line only containing EOL?

Keep track of when reading the beginning of the line.  If a `'\n'` is read at the beginning, stop

`getchar()` approach:

```
bool beginning = true;
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if (beginning) {
    if (ch == '\n') break;
  }
  // Do what ever you want with `ch` 
  beginning = ch == '\n';  
}
```

---

`fgets()` approach - needs more code to handle lines longer than N

```
#define N 1024
char buf[N+1];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) && buf[0] != '\n') {
  ; // Do something with buf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read one character at a time then you can with either `getchar` or `fgetc` depending upon whether or not you're reading from `stdin` or some other stream.

But you said you were reading strings, so I'm assuming `fgets` is more appropriate.

There are primarily two considerations:

1. maximum line length
2. whether or not to handle Windows versus non-Windows line endings

Even if you are a beginner--and I won't go into #2 here--you should know you can defend against it. I will at least say that if you compile on one platform and read from stdin from a redirected file from another platform, then you might have to write a defense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[32];  // relatively small buf makes testing easier
    int lineContinuation = 0;
    // If no characters are read, then fgets returns NULL.
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
       int l = strlen(buf); // No newline in buf if line len + newline exceeds sizeof(buf)
       if (buf[l-1] == '\n') {
          if (l == 1 && !lineContinuation) {
             break; // errno should indicate no error.
          }
          printf("send line ending (len=%d) to the parser\n", l);
          lineContinuation = 0;
       } else {
          lineContinuation = 1;
          printf("send line part (len=%d) to the parser\n", l);
       }
    }
    printf("check errno (%d) if you must handle unexpected end of input use cases\n", errno);
}
```